# How to group messages, in order, based on the contents

Tags: f#

The following code is used to display message in a Telegram bot.

When the application prints text, it is put in a queue and the queue gets consolidated and is flushed at regular intervals. This is meant to minimize the number of API calls.

At the same time, there is a limit of 4kb per message sent, so the messages get grouped as long as the total does not exceed 4kb.

Additionally, messages can be declared as markdown or plain text. All messages are typically sent as markdown, but error messages that contain stack traces, etc don't work in markdown mode, Telegram just ignores them.
There messages always get marked with some 'alert' symbol. And they have to be sent on their own.

For example:

```
message 1
message 2
Alert message 3
message 4
message 5
message LARGE SIZE 6
message 7
```

would be sent as:

```
message 1 + message 2 (markdown)
Alert message 3 (plain)
message 4 + message 5 (markdown)
message LARGE SIZE 6 (markdown)
message 7 (markdown)
```

this is the code used:

```ml
    let hasAlertCharacter (message: string) =
        message.Contains(interruptIcon)
        || message.Contains(waitForUserIcon)
        || message.Contains(waitForEventIcon)
        || message.Contains(warningIcon)
        || message.Contains(errorIcon)

    let sizeLimit = 4000
    let rec takeMessages (message: string) =
        let r, m = messageQueue.TryPeek()
        if r && message.Length + m.Length + 1 < sizeLimit then
            if hasAlertCharacter m then
                if String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) then
                    messageQueue.TryDequeue() |> ignore
                    m
                else
                    message
            else
                messageQueue.TryDequeue() |> ignore
                takeMessages $"{message}\n{m}"
        else
            message


    let messagesString = (takeMessages String.Empty).TrimStart('\n')
```

it works, but I think it's not very readable. Additionally, the code that sends the message is looking for the alert characters again:

```ml
    let parseMode =
        match hasAlertCharacter messagesString with
        | true  -> ParseMode.Default
        | false -> ParseMode.Markdown

    client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, messagesString, parseMode)
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore
```

so, overall, I am looking for a more elegant way to handle this.